# Targeting a title and changing in Jquery

Tags: jquery, load, title, attr

I am wondering how to select a element by it's title and then changing that title.

For example say an element has an title of "Hello", I would like to target that specific title of "Hello" and change it to "goodbye" after the page loads.

Would anyone be able to help me out on how to write this in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('[title="Hello"]').attr('title','Good Bye');
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the uber late response. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question back in 2013!

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector:

```
$('*[title="Hello"]');
```

Comment: Sorry for the uber late response. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question back in 2013!